# How to use group by to select only group row in these case scenarios

Tags: sql, subquery, group-by

I'm learning SQL for the first time and I was given these queries to do .

I wrote those statements to solve the problem and they work, but they don't use `group by`.

Can somebody please suggest how I change this? They should only use `group by` and maybe `where`, I don't think this assignment is supposed to use anything more advanced.

> What is the latest birth date of the presidents? (Youngest President)

```
SELECT birth, first_name, last_name 
FROM sampdb.president 
WHERE birth= (select MAX(birth) FROM sampdb.president);
+------------+------------+-----------+ 
| birth      | first_name | last_name |
+------------+------------+-----------+ 
| 1946-08-19 | William J. | Clinton   |
+------------+------------+-----------+ 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT birth, first_name, last_name 
FROM sampdb.president 
WHERE birth>=ALL(SELECT MAX(birth) FROM sampdb.president);  
+------------+------------+-----------+
| birth      | first_name | last_name |
+------------+------------+-----------+
| 1946-08-19 | William J. | Clinton   |
+------------+------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

> The earliest? (Oldest president)

```
SELECT birth, first_name, last_name 
FROM sampdb.president 
WHERE birth=(SELECT MIN(birth) FROM sampdb.president);
+------------+------------+------------+
| birth      | first_name | last_name  |
+------------+------------+------------+
| 1732-02-22 | George     | Washington |
+------------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: So, what is the question? How to rewrite the queries using `GROUP BY`?

Comment: You could write the `ALL` version simply as: `... WHERE birth >= ALL (SELECT birth FROM sampdb.president)` but otherwise your queries seem fine. I don't think there is need for use of `GROUP BY`

Comment: i don't see any need for a `GROUP BY` statement in you example, you are selecting 1 record based on 1 criteria. otherwise your query is correct.

Comment: exactly, i was told that i need to use group by for this query. But as i've already shown, there is no need. But what if i did use group by, what would i group by to get the same result shown above?

Comment: it was a badly worded exercise. it was under aggregate function exercises and group by exercises, so it was a misunderstanding by me.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, grouping *is* used but it is implicit: the absent `GROUP BY` is implied to be `GROUP BY ()`. So, you can specify it in your subquery if using an explicit GROUP BY clause is a requirement:

```
SELECT birth, first_name, last_name 
FROM sampdb.president 
WHERE birth = (SELECT MAX(birth) FROM sampdb.president GROUP BY ());
```

Not all SQL products support the explicit `GROUP BY ()`, though, and even when they do, the implemented behaviour may somewhat differ from that of the implicit `GROUP BY ()`. In particular, different output may be produced for explicit and implicit `GROUP BY ()` when the source dataset is empty. If, for instance, the `samdb.president` table was empty, this

```
SELECT MAX(birth) FROM sampdb.president GROUP BY ()
```

would result in no rows in such SQL products. In contrast, this query would produce a single row with a NULL in its single column:

```
SELECT MAX(birth) FROM sampdb.president
```

[Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2e3ab/1) and [SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21fc7/1), to name a few, are known to have this difference.

However, as you seem to be using the GROUP BY query as a (scalar) subquery, the final output of your query would be same for both implicit and explicit `GROUP BY` regardless of whether the `president` table was empty or not, meaning, if `GROUP BY ()` is supported in the SQL product you are using, you can add it explicitly to the subquery without worrying that it would affect the output.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a number of ways, depending on the platform.

in Oracle you can do something like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT birth, first_name, last_name 
      FROM sampdb.president
      ORDER BY birth)
WHERE rownum = 1
```

In SQL server you can something like this :

```
SELECT TOP 1 birth, first_name, last_name 
FROM sampdb.president
ORDER BY birth
```

In MySQL you can do something like this :

```
SELECT birth, first_name, last_name 
FROM sampdb.president
ORDER BY birth
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. i've now been informed that it didn't require group by. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries. As you can see by my answer, I don't use 'group by' either